Gradle Test: Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService()
I just tried to run my tests in a project via ./gradle test in the wsl.
Then it stopped with an exception:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.
Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().
java.io.IOException: Input/output error

Yesterday it all worked out, now I don't know what could be wrong. I already tried ./gradle --stop to stop the daemon, restarting the docker daemon and restarting my computer. Does anyone have an idea?

What worked for me:
In Intellj, go through all steps of "File > Repair IDE". Done.
